# Find a basis of a subspace in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to solve a system of equations for it I reduce the matrix, if I conclude that it has infinite solutions I want to find a basis of the solution space.

But in my code, I can't determine the basis for example if I consider the system

[image: example]

The basis should be (3, 1, 0)^T, (-2, 0, 1)^T

but in my code I'm finding that base wrong, any help?

The code is:

```
   clc;
clear all;

n = 3;
m = 4;

fprintf('Welcome to this program that performs some operations with matrices \n');
fprintf('Please press Enter to continue \n');

for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:m
        if j == m
            fprintf('y(%d,%d) = ', i, j);
            A(i, j) = input('');
        else
            fprintf('x(%d,%d) = ', i, j);
            A(i, j) = input('');
        end
    end
end

disp(A);

[B, solution] = AnalyzeSystem(A, n, m);

% If the system has a solution, execute the second function
if solution
    x = FindSolution(A, n, m);
    
    % Check if there are infinite solutions
    if isempty(x)
        fprintf('The system has infinite solutions\n');
        
        % Find the basis for the solution space
        basis = FindBasis(A, zeros(1, m-1), n, m);
        fprintf('This is a basis for the solution space, which generates the entire space:\n');
        disp(basis);
    end
end

function [B, solution] = AnalyzeSystem(A, n, m)
    B = A;

    found = false;
    row = 1;

    while ~(found) && row <= n
        if A(row, m) == 0
            row = row + 1;
        else
            norm = 0;
            for j = 1:m-1
                norm = norm + abs(A(row, j));
            end
            if norm == 0
                % found a null left side
                found = true;
            else
                % move to the next row
                row = row + 1;
            end
        end
    end

    if found
        fprintf('The system has no solution\n');
        solution = false;
    else
        fprintf('The system has a solution\n');
        solution = true;
    end
end

function x = FindSolution(A, n, m)
    % Procedure to find the number of linearly independent rows
    nonzero_rows = 0;
    row = 1;
    found = false;
    while ~(found) &&  row <= n
        if A(row, m) == 0
            row = row + 1;
        else
            norm = 0;
            for j = 1:m-1
                norm = norm + abs(A(row, j));
            end
            if norm == 0
                found = true;
            else
                row = row + 1;
                nonzero_rows = nonzero_rows + 1;
            end
        end
    end

    if found
        fprintf('The system has no solution\n');
        x = [];
    else
        fprintf('Does the system have a unique solution? ');
        if nonzero_rows == m - 1
            fprintf('The system has a unique solution\n');

            % Backward substitution
            x = zeros(1, m-1);
            for i = m-1:-1:1
                x(i) = A(i, m);
                for j = i+1:m-1
                    x(i) = x(i) - A(i, j) * x(j);
                end
                x(i) = x(i) / A(i, i);
            end

            fprintf('The solutions for this matrix are: \n');
            disp(x);
        else
            fprintf('The system has more than one solution (free variables).\n');
            x = [];
        end
    end
end

function x = FindBasis(A, b, n, m)
    % Assumes that the system has infinite solutions
    
    % Reduce the matrix to reduced row-echelon form
    [A_reduced, solution] = RowReduce([A, b'], n, m+1);
    
    % Find the basis for the homogeneous solution space
    if solution
        basis = FindBasisRows(A_reduced, n, m+1);
        x = basis(:, 1:m-1);
    else
        x = [];
    end
end

function [B, solution] = RowReduce(A, n, m)
    B = A;

    for col = 1:m-1
        pos = col;
        found = false;

        while ~(found) && pos <= n
            if B(pos, col) == 0
                pos = pos + 1;
            else
                found = true;
            end
        end

        if found
            for i = pos+1:n
                C = -B(i, col) / B(pos, col);
                for j = col:m
                    B(i, j) = B(i, j) + C * B(pos, j);
                end
            end

            if ~(pos == col)
                for j = col:m
                    aux = B(pos, j);
                    B(pos, j) = B(col, j);
                    B(col, j) = aux;
                end
            end
        end
    end
    
    % Check if there are completely null rows (excluding the column of independent terms)
    null_rows = all(B(:, 1:m-1) == 0, 2);
    
    % Check if any null row has a non-zero independent term
    solution = true;  % Initialize solution as true

    for i = 1:n
        if null_rows(i) && B(i, m) ~= 0
            solution = false;
            break;  % Exit the loop if a null row with a non-zero independent term is found
        end
    end
end

function basis = FindBasisRows(A, n, m)
    basis = [];

    for i = 1:n
        j = 1;
        while j < m && A(i, j) == 0
            j = j + 1;
        end

        if j == m
            basis = [basis; A(i, 1:m-1)];
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I didn't look at your code, but in case it helps, this can be solved with Matlab's [`null`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html) function: `null([2 -6 4; -1 3 -2; -3 9 -6], 'r')`